# Git and Java package name issue

Tags: java, git, eclipse, package

I am using Java Eclipse IDE with git. I am using a package name as hello.git to store my source code in the foulder src. When I apply the local commit, the package is splitted in two foulders.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. `hello.git` pretty much means there's a folder called "hello" with a folder called "git" inside, both of which are also Java packages.

Comment: This is exactly how Java stores source files. Eclipse is simply applying Java-specific knowledge to present the package structure in a useful way.

Comment: In Java the package structure corresponds to a folder structure on the disk. Some IDEs have an option to compress the representation like Eclipse does - if a package is empty (no files in the disk, only other folders in it), it converts it into <package><dot><subpackage>. So `org.my.package.name` is just a simplified representation that you have an `org` folder which only has a `my` folder which only has a `package` folder which only has a `name` folder.